# How blank verse is “closest to the natural rhythms of English speech”?

Tags: poetry, meter

I was reading a book and in that it was written

> Shakespeare has used this poetic form (the blank verse) skillfully in his dramas because it is closest to the natural rhythms of English speech, and can be adopted to various levels of discourse.

A simple Google search showed me that blank verse can be composed in any meter and with any amount of feet per line. The four standard feet for blank verse are

- iamb
- trochee
- anapest
- dactyl

Out of these the iamb is generally the predominant foot.

But how is it closest to the natural rhythms of English speech?

Comment: What the book means by *blank verse* is probably *unrhymed iambic pentameter*.

Comment: Another question that addresses how iambic pentameter is closest to the rhythms of English speech is [this one](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/9024/289)